# SurfaceHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888) fails on some devices and not others

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a game app with the following Views structure. First I have an empty FrameLayout like so:

```
FrameLayout game_frame_layout = new FrameLayout(getApplicationContext());
```

Then I add two views to it like so:

```
game_frame_layout.addView(customView);
game_frame_layout.addView(butView);
```

The customView is for displaying all sorts of moving game graphics while the butView displays some ImageButtons on top of the moving grapics. The customView is an instance of a class CustomView which extends SurfaceView.

CustomView includes the following code

```
    void updateView() 
    {
        final SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

        try 
        {
                Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                if (canvas != null) 
                {
                    onDraw(canvas);

                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The line `holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);` is a recent addition (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052146/setting-the-pixelformat)). Without that line, my animated graphics appear to be in a format with too few colours (by experiment I deduced it was "RGB_565"), so I get some [banding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_banding) artifacts. When I added the setFormat line, the graphics appear perfectly (without banding) on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (Android 3.1)... but on three other devices: a Samsung GT-l9100 (4.1.2), a Nexus 7 ME370T 4.4.2 and a HTC One X 4.2.2 I only see the buttons corresponding to butView against an entirely black background. There is no indication in the logs that the program has crashed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need transparency for that surface or could you also give `PixelFormat.RGB_888` a shot?

Comment: Are your buttons still moving on your "black" moving graphics?

Answer (score 2):

Probably not all android devices support a 32/24 bit pixel format so that's why 565 is always working while 888 might fail.
You might try to understand if it's a problem with the hardware acceleration trying to disable it

Comment: I can confirm that disabling hardware acceleration did not fix the problem.

Comment: Seems strange that its the newer devices that are failing.

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you change the order you add them to the `game_frame_layout`?
First the butView and then the customView:

```
game_frame_layout.addView(butView);
game_frame_layout.addView(customView);
```

I assume the butView won't be visible, but i'm curious whether the customView renders its content properly.

Comment: Black screen - no buttons.

Comment: Did you find any changes in the surfaceview/holder or view drawing mechanism between Honeycomb and JellyBean release? seems strange that your jellybean devices fail to display.

Answer (score 1):

Your application doesn't seems to be working post ICS. ICS saw major revisions in the graphics department, the most significant being introduction of `TextureView` which is designed to address the shortcomings of `SurfaceView`. Try extending `TextureView` instead of `SurfaceView` for your `CustomView` class. For more info visit [Android 4.0 Graphics and Animation](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/11/android-40-graphics-and-animations.html)

Comment: I know its not an ideal solution because it will not work for lower API levels but with decreasing share of Pre-ICS devices, this might be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious if you set `butView`'s background to transparent.

```
butView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: No change - still all black behind buttons.